# Can a group G in which $x^2 = 1$ for every $x \in G,$ be infinite?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I know that a group like above is abelian. Can anyone give an example if this group can be infinite? Or even have more than 2 elements?

My try: I can only imagine such a group with 1 or 2 elements. E.g. {1}, {1, -1}, with operator defined as usual multiplication of real numbers.  My book has a question : If a group G in which $x^2 = 1$ for every $x \in G,$ then (a) G is finite, (b) G is abelian. As per my knowledge, both should be true, but the answer is given as (b) only. Need an example to understand this further.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be any set, finite or infinite, and let $G=\wp(X)$. The group operation in $G$ is symmetric difference: $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$. The identity element is $1_G=\varnothing$: $A\triangle\varnothing=A$ for each $A\in G$. And since $A\triangle A=\varnothing$ for each $A\in G$, every element of the group satisfies the equation $x^2=1_G$. Thus, there are arbitrarily large groups with that property, since the cardinality of $G$ is $2^{|X|}$.

If $G$ is finite, its order must of course be a power of $2$, but with a little more work you can get groups of this kind of any infinite cardinality, not just powers of $2$. If $X$ is infinite, let $G_f=\{F\subseteq X:F\text{ is finite}\}$. Then $G_f$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $|G_f|=|X|$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the direct product of infinitely many cyclic groups of order $2$ is infinite and every element has order 2 or 1. In fact every group satisfying $x^2=1$ can be considered a vector space over the field with 2 elements, so it has a basis $X$ and whence is isomorphic to the direct product  of $|X|$ copies of $C_2$.

Comment: A vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with a basis $X$ is isomorphic to the direct sum, not product, of $|X|$ copies of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: It is the direct product (as opposite to rhe Cartesian product).

Comment: The original group was multiplicatice and the law $x^2=1$. When we turn it into a vector space the operation becomes additive and the law becomes $2x=0$. The space is thus a direct sum while the original group is then  a direct product.

Comment: This is incorrect. Whether we think of the group law as multiplicative or additive has no bearing on the meaning of the terms "direct sum" versus "direct product." Both are defined for a family of abelian groups and the latter means the cartesian product and is strictly larger in the infinite case.

Comment: The direct sum $\bigoplus_X \mathbb{F}_2$ is a vector space with basis $X$, and consists of finite formal linear combinations of elements of $X$; the direct product $\prod_X \mathbb{F}_2$ consists of all sequences and has a strictly larger basis than $X$ in the infinite case. The former is a proper subspace of the latter.

Comment: Direct sums are used for additive structures. Direct products - for multiplicative.I consider the direct product of groups $C_2$, not direct sums of fields.

Comment: I am telling you very clearly that this is incorrect. You can take the direct sum of nonabelian groups and you can take the direct product of abelian groups. Here are the Wikipedia articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Types_of_direct_sum, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product#Direct_product_of_modules

Comment: You are arguing with somebody who knows. That is not wise.

Comment: I guess this is why product and coproduct were introduced in cetegory theory. I think this is just a difference in terminology among algebraists as to whether one refers to the product or coproduct as the direct sum. For abelian groups, I'd always learned direct sum and Cartesian product. I think this is to avoid direct product entirely, since it's an overloaded term.

Comment: H. Neumann's classic "Varieties of Groups" is the only book I have to hand which talks about this. In Section 1.5, she defines the Cartesian Product of groups to be the "big" product and Direct Product to be the finitely-based version. I prefer this to Wikipedia's convention, which I have always found confusing (as I can see no meaningful reason why "product" and "sum" are assigned to those structures and not the other way round). The convention used by H. Neumann allows us to use direct sum for additive structures and direct product for multiplicative, as JCAA suggests. I find this pleasing.

Comment: Often people use restricted and unrestricted, like with wreath products. Rotman uses direct sum and direct product for abelian groups. I couldn't find anything in Robinson about it. I must admit I didn't think to look in HN's book. (I will forever know it as 'Peter Neumann's mother's book', because Peter always refers to it as 'my mother's book'. Which is fair, of course.)

Comment: Tom Hungerford’s graduate text is the only one on hand that deals with this. He calls the big one the *direct product* or *complete direct sum*, and the little one the *weak direct product*, noting that it is often called the *direct sum* when the groups are Abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any nonempty set, $G$ any group and consider the set of all functions

$$Func(X,G)=\{f:X\to G\}$$

On this set define pointwise group operation:

$$(f*g)(x):=f(x)g(x)$$

It is easy to see that $Func(X,G)$ together with $*$ is a group. The neutral element is the constant $id(x)=e_G$ function.

Note that $|Func(X,G)|=|G|^{|X|}$ in terms of cardinal numbers.

So now if we take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ then you can easily check that $f*f=id$ for any $f\in Func(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. Furthermore $Func(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ can be arbitrarly big, depending on $X$. In particular $Func(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is infinite.

The $Func(X,G)$ can be considered as a special case of [infinite direct product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Infinite_direct_products). Here $X$ plays the role of the index set and we take the direct product over $X$ many copies of $G$.